# Magento 2.4.2 GraphQL not get uid from customerCart and cart query

Tags: magento2, cart, customer, graphql

**I installed Magento 2.4.2**

**According to Magento GraphQL DevDocs [updateCartItems](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/update-cart-items.html) mutation cart_item_id is Deprecated. Use cart_item_uid instead. The unique ID assigned when a customer places an item in the cart.**

**I can not get cart item's uid from [customerCart](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/customer-cart.html) and [cart](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/cart.html) query.**

**Please help me.**

[image]

Comment: Please check example usage code: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/customer-cart.html#example-usage

Comment: As per the example code, there are not defined "uid" parameter in the request. There are only defined "id" then get "uid" in response.

Comment: Yes but i can not get uid from response. I try this but not working. Please give me best solution for it. How to get uid. from cart query. I need this uid for other cart operation.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your backend magento installation is the latest 2.4.2 or newer version, uuid were added recently on that release to replace number ids

check release notes: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-2.html#graphql

Comment: Yes i installed and use magento 2.4.2 but i can't get uid. Please help me.